# Comparing two lists and extracting elements

Tags: python

My code

```
with open('freq1.txt') as f:
    next(f, None)
    list1 = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

with open('freq2.txt') as f:
    next(f, None)
    list2 = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

print set(list1).intersection(list2)
```

But I got
set([])
For example I have two lists

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=[3,2,7,5,9]
```

I want list with all elements from list1 and list2

```
newlist=[1,2,3,4,5,7,9]
```

How to write this?

EDIT
I would like to use one way using list comprehensions.

```
list1=[1.0,2.0,3.1,4.2]
list2=[3.0,2.0,7.2,5.1,9.2]
list3=[2.1,4.2,5.1,9.2]

su1 = list1 + [x for x in list2 if x not in list1]
su2= su1 + [x for x in list3 if x not in su1]
su2=sorted(su2)
print su2list1=[1.0,2.0,3.1,4.2]
list2=[3.0,2.0,7.2,5.1,9.2]
list3=[2.1,4.2,5.1,9.2]

su1 = list1 + [x for x in list2 if x not in list1]
su2= su1 + [x for x in list3 if x not in su1]
su2=sorted(su2)
print su2
```

Works very nice

```
[1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 3.0, 3.1, 4.2, 5.1, 7.2, 9.2]
```

Comment: @GarrettR Yes,latter i will have more lists.

Comment: If you want the elements, sorted you should use my solution as it guarantees the elements are returned in increasing order

Comment: The posted solutions are not general, they require that you have reals and or integers, if your input is something else you would get some possibly unexpected results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `set.union()`:

```
>>> set(list1).union(list2)
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9])
```

If you want a list as the result (which is not necessary if you don't want to use the list's attributes like indexing and **if you are only dealing with integers** because, since the hash of integers is equal to themselves (except -1 which is -2) the `set()` object will preserve the order as well)  you can call the `list()` function on the result of `union()`.

```
>>> list(set(list1).union(list2))
```

Comment: I am not totally sure but I believe sets are unordered containers.  The order is dependent on the hash - the user has no control over the order, so if the inputs vary from reals or integers the ordered output will be different than the expected.  I am only mentioning this because you make a really strong statement above that does not hold for many cases

Comment: @PyNEwbie Yes I just mentioned that this is for integers.

Comment: @Kasramvd In my case I have reals not integers.

Comment: @RichardRublev So you shouldn't use `set()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the elements sorted in ascending order

```
sorted_unique = sorted(set(list1+list2))
```

Comment: See my comment above, this does not hold for all cases, sorting a list before converting to a set seems noisy and also unnecessary if the input in an integer that is set(sorted([1,2,3,4]+[5,6,7,8,9])) gives the same output as set(sorted([1,2,4,3]+[5,6,7,8,9]))